# Winston Not Logging

Tags: node.js, express, docker, winston

I have winston on my node js app with express running. I have it setup to log to a port which has a log app listening on it. I am running my app and the only way the logs appear on the other port is when i shut down my app and it seems as if all the logs are then sent at that point. Is there some config that I am missing that sends the logs immediately to the port instead of having it send only on server shutdown?

I am also running these apps on docker and I don't believe it is a docker issue as when I run it locally the same issue occurs.

EDIT- I'm using only the following:

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.loggers.add('main', {
  http: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9514
  }
});
```

Comment: Please post your Winston configuration so we can better troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: I just tested it with a similar configuration and it works correctly for me. The server at `http://localhost:9514/` should receive a request with a body that looks something like `{"method":"collect","params":{"level":"info","message":"test","meta":{}}}`. What does your HTTP server on port 9514 receive?

Comment: the HTTP server on port 9514 does receive the logs, ONLY after i shutdown my app. Seems like shutting down my app pushes the logs to that port instead of having the app up and running and logging on demand

Comment: Are the logs sent with multiple requests or just one large request when the app shuts down?

Comment: its listed as separate log messages but the timestamp are all the same

Comment: I changed from http to winston-syslog and now it is aggregating all the messages as one message BUT still only showing up after server shutdown.